# What happens if I forget comma in my create sqlite table for a column?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.wtf("x", " database CREATED!!! -------------------------");
    db.execSQL("create table userData ("
            + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
            + "name text,"
            + "password text,"
            + "hero1_score int,"
            + "hero2_score int,"
            + "hero3_score int,"
            + "hero4_score int,"
            + "hero5_score int"    //forget comma here - what happens?
            + "loggedin int"
            + ");");
```

When i try to add row in my userData table, it gives me error :
"can't find loggedin column" , I recognized the error was this simple comma. Apparently, any other stuff that goes after last comma is not included in actual sql command "CREATE TABLE".

Can someone explain why this is like that?

Comment: Because sqlite mostly doesn't care about about column type... You can even write `column1 fu*inawesometype plus spaces` (of course without *) and it will be valid create statement...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That last part of the SQL string reads `,hero5_score intloggedin int);`. The declared type of column `hero5_score` becomes `intloggedin int` and it gets [integer affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: glad, a coder with 75k reputation answers my question!