# How to fix "sqlite3.OperationalError: table users has 4 columns but 5 values were supplied"?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3
from config import settings

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['PREFIX'])
client.remove_command('help')

connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
        name TEXT,
        id INT,
        cash bigint,
        rep INT
        lvl INT
    )""")

    for guild in client.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
                cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
            else:
                pass

    connection.comit()
    print('Bot connected')


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f"SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}").fetchone() is None:
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
        connection.comit()
    else:
        pass


@client.command(aluases = ['balance', 'cash'])
async def __balance(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
                description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.author}** составляет **{"cursor.execute(SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".fromat(ctx.author.id).fetchone()[0]}**"""
        ))
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(
            description = f"""Баланс пользователя **{ctx.member}** составляет **{"cursor.execute(SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {}".fromat(ctx.member.id).fetchone()[0]}**"""
        ))
client.run(settings['TOKEN'])
```

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gnati\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "bot.py", line 27, in on_ready
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{member}', {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
sqlite3.OperationalError: table users has 4 columns but 5 values were supplied
```

Comment: Doesn't the last line in the error message clearly tell you what's wrong?

Comment: Please edit this question to include what you have done to fix it and research you have done.

Comment: The last line shows the error like @Shiva said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```py
> cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
>     name TEXT,
>     id INT,
>     cash bigint,
>     rep INT
>     lvl INT
> )""")
> ```

Since there is no comma between `rep INT` and `lvl INT`, the table has only 4 columns where you think it has 5.

What actually happens when this `CREATE TABLE` statement is executed is explained here: [What happens if I forget comma in my create sqlite table for a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32502225/what-happens-if-i-forget-comma-in-my-create-sqlite-table-for-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused when you create the table, you have forgotten a comma in your SQL query.

To fix it use this:

```py
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    name TEXT,
    id INT,
    cash bigint,
    rep INT,
    lvl INT
)""")
```